# When to use keyword arguments for class initialisation?

Tags: python, class, oop, keyword-argument

When creating my own classes I can't work out when I should or shouldn't use keyword arguments.

**Are there any specific circumstances or general rules of thumb on this?**

As far as I can tell:

**Pros:**

1. Explicit definition so makes it harder for variables to get put in the wrong order
2. Makes the code more readable

**Cons:**

1. By having a keyword argument you need to also supply a default value, which means instances can be initialised without any arguments being supplied.

Please see below MyClassA and MyClassB which illustrate these two points:

```
class MyClassA():

    def __init__(self,name,city):

        self.name = name
        self.city = city

x = MyClassA('Andy','New York')



class MyClassB():

    def __init__(self,name=None,city=None):

        self.name = name
        self.city = city

 y = MyClassB(city='New York',name='Andy')
```

Comment: Note that whether or not you use keywords arguments is independent of whether you assign default values to a parameter. `MyClassA(name='Andy', city='New York')` and `MyClassB('Andy', 'New York')` would both work. The difference is that using keyword *arguments*, you aren't constrained by the order in which the parameters were defined. Also, `MyClassB()` is legal (because of the default values) while `MyClassA()` is not.

Comment: Try `x = MyClassB('Andy','New York')` for your second example

Comment: Your assessment of pros and cons is pretty good, I think.  If getting default values on initialization worries you, then default them to `None` and raise an exception if the caller doesn't supply values.

Comment: @chepner Thats really interesing about `x = MyClassA(name='Andy',city='New York')`  working! I just tried it and the order can even be changed. 

That seems like a way i can make my code readable without presenting the issue of MyClass() being legal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, in both cases, you can pass arguments as keyword arguments:

```
x = MyClassA(city='New York', name='Andy')
```

would also work. And this:

```
x = MyClassA(name='Andy', city='New York')
```

would also work.

The general rule of thumb (IMHO): if it is obvious at the call site what are the arguments - no need in keywords, otherwise - **Explicit is better than implicit**.

And just FYI, you can force usage of keyword args like so:

```
def fun(positional_arg1, *, keyword_only_arg1, keyword_only_arg2): ...
```

which means that you can't call `fun` with positional arguments:

```
>>> fun(1, 2, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: fun() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

and you have to provide all arguments:

```
>>> fun(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: fun() missing 2 required keyword-only arguments: 
'keyword_only_arg1' and 'keyword_only_arg2'
```

So the only way to call `fun` is:

```
fun(1, keyword_only_arg1=1, keyword_only_arg2=3)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little further on your last example of forcing keyword args? Isn't * use to unpack iterables? Can't quite see the connection with forcing usage of keywords

Comment: @Andy That's only if `*` is part of a parameter name. A `*` by itself is not an actual parameter, but a separator between parameters that can be specified by positional arguments, and parameters that can *only* be specified by keyword arguments.

Comment: Thats fantastic. Using * seems to be a good solution. I can then force keywords without creating defaults.

Is this commonly used by experienced programmers when making classes?

Comment: I'd say it is more common when `super` is used, as using keyword arguments facilities the correct handling of arguments meant to be passed untouched to methods farther along the MRO.

Comment: Note also that default values neither allow nor require keyword arguments to be used. You can use a keyword argument to set a parameter with no default value, and you can use a positional argument to set a parameter with a default value.

Comment: @chepner@Yevhen Kuzmovych Thanks for the help on this. Need to digest all the useful information you have been given me

Comment: @Andy Over at software engineering a user has compiled [lists](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/384703) of good and not-so-good cases for the use of keyword-only arguments, plus some potential pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `argument=value` in 2 cases:

1 - When you are using a function that has a lot of arguments but you only want to set specific parameters

```
def function(a=None, b=0, c=1, d=None, ......................z=None):
    .....
    return value

function(d='walk', g=4)
```

2 - When you don't know the order of parameters, as pointed by [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)

```
function(13,14, 'default', 'walk',......)
function(a=13, d='walk')
```